# How can I use Extension functions from the parent class for my own subclass in Tests?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, testing, extension-methods, subclass

I have a class derived from NSTreeController named CSMCustomTreeController and imported the header data from some Extensions of NSTreeController

**CSMCustomTreeController.h**

```
#import "NSTreeController_Extensions.h"


@interface CSMCustomTreeController : NSTreeController {
...
```

The Extension ist defined **NSTreeController_Extensions.h**:

```
#import "NSTreeController_Extensions.h"
#import "NSTreeNode_Extensions.h"
#import "NSIndexPath_Extensions.h"
#import "NSArray_Extensions.h"

@implementation NSTreeController (ESExtensions)
...
```

I can use all the defined Functions from ESExtensions in my normal target, but in my TestCases it seems that my subclass doesn't know anything about the extension functions... :(

Only my testcases are added to the Test-Target...

Anybody a clue?

Comment: Are you importing both headers into your test case class?

Comment: that was the point... :( I thought it would be enough to import the header file of the category to the CSMCustomTreeController, but I had to import it also additionally to the test case... I already noticed that yesterday, but I couldnt answer my own question within the first 24 hours. If you write an answer I will mark it as right! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that *both* headers (`CSMCustomTreeController.h` and `NSTreeController_Extensions.h`) are imported into your test case class.

If you don't import the header containing the category, the test case class will not be able to find your category methods.